# What is the data-type return of Couchbase when you 'Get' an attachment (jpg)

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, couchbase, attachment

I'm new in Couchbase.

I'm using node js express + Couchbase.

This is my model for creating an http request for getting an image attachment on couchbase server:

```
ModuleModel.getAttachment = function(id, name, sessionId, callback){

    var options = {
    url: config.sync.url+id+'/'+name,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'image/jpeg', "Cookie":sessionId }
    };
    request(options, function(error, response) {
      if(error){
          console.log("1"+error);
          return callback(error, null);
      }
    console.log(response.body);
         callback(null,response.body);
  });
}
```

it returns a very long string like this:

> ����QWc��{wfE,�Q'�Q��9Y>ռg�X����>�<շ�� ���t�{o��5ۓ�:�Sӻ��r�vuSO�IV�����dZ#5M7�F�Y.XB����Vv�4sT�y����ߦ      �P����=>'���GQW}��s�%zJ�q;�\�=l���P

I've tried to convert that string into base64 then into image but id didn;t work

How to convert that data into an image? Thanks!

Comment: What were you using to convert to base 64? Were you taking the result and putting it in a `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[converted binary stream]" />` tag?

Comment: Hi Peter,
this code is used by the admin side programmer:
AttachmentModel.create=function(data,callback){

  var link = data.link;
  var fileName= data.name;
  var id= uuid();

  var options = {
        url: config.admin.url+'/'+id +'/'+fileName,
        method: "PUT",
        header:'Content-Type: image/png' 
    };

    fs.createReadStream(link).pipe(
        request(options, (err, response) => {
        })
    )

    callback(null,id);
};

How ca i get that then convert to image?

Comment: From that it seems like you're creating PNG images? If so, check if the response headers are `image/png`. Then convert the response body using `var encoded = btoa(response.body);`, append `data:image/png;base64,` and set that whole string as the value of `src` attribute in `<img />` and see if that works.

Comment: But really it seems to me that what you really want is to have routing for URLs which correspond to image attachments, and when you make a request to an attachment URL you query the database and receive the corresponding attachment datastream as a response, which the client would then see as an image.

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
--------my code---->
var encoded = btoa(json);
         var link = "data:image/png;base64/"+encoded;
    $('#1').attr('src', link);

Comment: `data:image/png;base64/` should be `data:image/png;base64,` with a comma at the end. If that doesn't work, I'm just not familiar enough either Couchbase and manipulating binary data in JS to have an idea of how to proceed. But I will wildly guess that unless you have some special use for these images, it might be best to create routing for these attachments (like `/assets/{id}/`) and get the image via the resulting URLs, not directly as binary data consumed by a JS concern.

Comment: I didn't work also, it should be "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/"+base64String, anyways, thanks for concern sir Peter.

Comment: Before I was enable to get image by just accessing url+attatchmentName/attachmentID thru 4985, the problem is you cannot access thru 4985 when it comes to production so I get image thru 4984 that comes up with that strange string.